# Comments on comments and communicating with a commenter

Tags: support, comment

If I respond to a comment with a comment or question directed to the commenter, does the commenter necessarily see it?

If not, is there any way I can draw their attention to it? I assumed the site would have a personal message feature, but if it does, I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 6):

It depends -- if you use the `@-reply` feature and the other person is already in the thread, then yes they will receive a notification.

Let's look at an example:

[image: comments example]

In this picture, I've underlined the `@-replies` and circled various people who received replies in the course of the conversation. The user named `Yannis` is highlighted in gray because he was the owner of the post that these comments are attached to.

Through the course of the conversation, `Yannis` received the replies to `@YannisRizos`, both because he was "pinged" as well as because he owned the post. The user `John Dibling` received notice about any posts that included `@JohnDibling` in the body at all, just as `Shog9` received messages directed towards `@Shog9`.

Later on in the conversation, someone else (not Yannis) responds to `McCannot` as well.

Noteworthy: you ***cannot*** ping more than one person in a comment. Thus, if you wish to respond to BOTH another commentor as well as the post owner, you must `@-reply` the other commentor and you can mention the post owner; the latter will be notified regardless of `@` usage.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have a problem with some user names. For example for [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/8402/stephane-laurent) user; the @-username doesn't work.